# Code igniter routes making internal server error

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes

Been stuck on this for hours, hope it is not something to simple.

So I'm trying to route 3 vars from one URL to another with this code:

```
$route['activate_email/(:any)/(:any)/(:any)'] = "user/activate/$1/$2/$3";
```

and the user controller code:

```
public function activate($code='', $email='', $id=''){
    die("1");
    //Check vars
    if(empty($code) || empty($email) || empty($id) || !is_numeric(ceil($id))){
        die("BAD");         
    }

    //Check details in DB
    $result = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `companies` WHERE `id` = ?", array($id))->result_array();

    print_r($result);
    exit;


}
```

Result:

Internal Server Error

The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator, cgiadmin@yourhostingaccount.com and inform them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done that may have caused the error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

Additionally, a 500 Internal Server Error error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Thanks for any help

Comment: Internal Server Error can happen when you do something wrong in your `.htaccess` file. Did you set it? What is in it?

Comment: when you use die() in a function the code that comes after never gets executed.. so how can you check your vars ?

Comment: @lollo He can't even get the `"1"` from the `die()`. His problem isn't about the variables, he get an Internal Server Error...

Comment: sorry.. now i think it was for debug.... @user1977434 are you sure you're passing a float value into [ceil()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ceil.php) function?

Answer (score 1):

It might be .htaccess issue. Try putting this code in your .htaccess and give it a try?

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]

And also try setting this option in your config file config['log_threshold'] to 4 and check  exactly where the issue is coming from?